# Set cookie on localhost

Tags: node.js, angular, express, cookies, localhost

I know this is kinda frequently asked question and it has been answered a lot of times. But all of these are from 2013 and I am starting to think that a lot changed since then.

I am trying to set cookie on localhost via Node.js Express, back-end running locally on localhost:3000 and front-end on localhost:4200 (works on my dev and prod domain) but I am quite unsuccessful. I tried to remove and play with all properties as was suggested here, but without success.

This is my standard setting

```
expires: new Date(Date.now() + process.env.CART_COOKIE_EXPIRES_IN * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000),
domain: req.get('origin'),
httpOnly: true
```

And I set `secure: true` on deployed sites.

I have tried to set domain into `localhost`, `.localhost`, `127.0.0.1`, `false`, `null`. I tried to remove all properties such as `httpOnly`, `domain` and leave there only expiration date, but still unsuccessful.

I even downloaded `dnsmasq` library and setup my local DNS record so I could use address like `http://mysite.dev.test:4200/` to have at least two dots in address as some people here recommended and set domain to `.mysite.dev.test` or `mysite.dev.test`, but still nothing.

I also tried all of these in browsers I use for front-end development such as Chrome, Opera, Safari and Firefox, no difference.

I am starting to be really desperate as I went through every topic I found, tried out almost every possible answer. So is anyone here who would be willing to share with me his/her know how to develop on localhost using cookies with recent versions? I would be extremely grateful.

Comment: Unless you're serving your front end and back end on the same domain *and port*, you will not be able to use cookies to share data between them. This is why tokens are preferred. You're fighting a losing battle. A battle I have fought before, and lost.

Comment: @R.Richards thank you for reply! So do you think this may be solved by using for example by some kind of reverse proxy such as Nginx locally and serve these under same port?

Comment: I couldn't say for sure. If the cookies have the same domain and port in the end, then it could work. May be work a try.

Comment: @R.Richards it worked like a charm, easy setup both under localhost:8080 for FE and localhost:8080/api/* for BE, thank you very much for clarification! :-)